# SELECT with LIKE in an order with the MOST SIMILAR

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a table with the following data:

[image]

If I do the query: `SELECT name FROM table LIKE '%joao%'`

This is result:

[image]

If I do the query: `SELECT * from z_teste WHERE name LIKE '%joao%' ORDER BY name ASC`

This is result:

[image]

If I do the query: `SELECT * from z_teste WHERE name LIKE '%joao%' ORDER BY name DESC`

This is result:

[image]

But how do I get him to organize himself in the order of "more likely
"?

The field that is most similar is from id 4, just after the 5 then the 2 and so on.

How to do this ordination?

Comment: See full text indexes or the Levenshtein distance algorithm

Comment: @Strawberry I do not understand very well, can you explain better?